# Number of times a table is read, written to and updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000, trace

Is there a way I can find out the number of times a table is read, updated, added to or has had rows deleted during a trace?

I am creating the trace in SQL using `sp_trace_setstatus`, not using the Sql Profiler UI.

I am using `sp_trace_setevent` and `::fn_trace_gettable` to get my current stats, but cannot find out how to get the stats regarding the table.

I would like to run this trace on both SQL 2000 and SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Why tags for both 2000 and 2008 R2?

Comment: @MartinSmith Updated my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Profiler, I tested this using SQL Server 2008. I don't know if the output will be the same in MSSQL 2000.

Using the template: TSQL_Replay

1. Select the Events Selection Tab
2. Check Show all events
3. Expand Performance then check Showplan XML
4. When you run your trace you will see the following events appear

[image]

When you select Showplan XML, you will see the Execution plan generated by the query

[image]

If you hover your mouse over the Delete event, as in my example you will get the number of 
rows and other information related to the query

**Update 15:50**

Here is the SQL exported by profiler for the showplan XML event.

```
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 3, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 60, @on
```

122 is the event and then there is an id for each column selected in profiler for Showplan XML when I exported the trace to a file.

Here is the list of events you can trace from Microsoft: [Trace Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the direct SQL needed for this?

Comment: @rhughes, In profiler, start your trace and then stop it. Next select File -> Export -> Script Trace Definition -> For SQL Server and the version that you want

Comment: I am doing this trace in SQL rather than the profiler itself using `sp_trace_setstatus`. I have updated my question to make it a bit clearer

Comment: @rhughes I have updated my answer